# Add extra class to last item in WP loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this to pull out the four most popular posts based on comments:

```
        <?php
            $pc = new WP_Query('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
            <?php while ($pc->have_posts()) : $pc->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="popular-post-item">
            <span class="popular-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="post-links"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
            <span class="popular-author">by: <?php the_author() ?></span> 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="action">Read Full Article</a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

What I need is the fourth:

```
        <div class="popular-post-item">
```

to have another class added called .last

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use $pc->post_count to get the number of posts returned by WP_Query and compare it to iterator.

```
    <?php
        $pc = new WP_Query('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=4'); 
        $count = $pc->post_count;
        $i = 0;
        ?>
    <?php while ($pc->have_posts()) : $pc->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="popular-post-item<?php if ($i === $count) echo ' last'; ?>">
            <span class="popular-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="post-links"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
            <span class="popular-author">by: <?php the_author() ?></span> 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="action">Read Full Article</a>
        </div>
        <?php
            // incriment counter
            $i++;
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: EDIT: I was not completely sure if post_count was 1 or 0 based.

Comment: I had to set $i to 1 for this to work since the post_count will start with 1 not 0.

Answer (score 8):

You'll want to use the `current_post` and `post_count` properties of the query result with a ternary.

Unlike some are suggesting, you don't have to create a separate counter variable (since the `current_post` property is already an index number of the result):

```
<?php
$pc = new WP_Query('orderby=comment_count&posts_per_page=4');
while ($pc->have_posts()) :
    $pc->the_post();
?>
<div class="popular-post-item<?php echo $pc->current_post + 1 === $pc->post_count ? ' last' : '' ?>">
    <span class="popular-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="post-links"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <span class="popular-author">by: <?php the_author() ?></span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="action">Read Full Article</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

(Note that the portion of code that's added is just `<?php echo $pc->current_post + 1 === $pc->post_count ? ' last' : '' ?>`, and the reason that you have to add 1 to the current post number is because one number is a zero-based index, and the other is a one-based count.)

Another option would be to use a pseudo-selector, but that depends on what browsers you need to support.